# Can I make a variable persist across multiple function calls but be local to each thread in openMP fortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

Using openMP in Fortran, is there any way to create a variable which is local to each thread but saved between function calls? Basically like a 'save' variable which is local to each thread.

For example, I'm trying to implement the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to generate uniform random numbers, with the following code (which I know works perfectly when NOT called in an openMP parallel region):

```
function rand_norm(seed)
    implicit none
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: seed
    real*8 :: rand_norm
    real*8 :: u, v
    real*8, save :: second_rand
    integer, save :: avail_flag = 0

    if (avail_flag.eq.1) then
        rand_norm = second_rand
        avail_flag = 0
        return
    end if

    avail_flag = 1

    u = rand_float(seed)
    v = rand_float(seed)

    second_rand = sqrt(-2.D0*log(u))*cos(2.D0*PI*v)
    rand_norm = sqrt(-2.D0*log(u))*sin(2.D0*PI*v)

end function
```

However, the problem arises that when calling this from within a parallel region, the two 'save' variables are now shared between threads, which defeats the purpose.

Is there any simple way to make these two variables local to each thread, but still persist between function calls?

I'm aware there are other ways to solve this problem (which I have done in a fairly messy way in the past), so if what I'm asking isn't directly possible, what is the best way to get around the issue? Should I just feed in the 'saved' values as arguments to the function?

Comment: Personally I'd avoid such impure functions in parallel programs, which tend to lead to the kind of problem you currently face.  But I'll be interested to see if anyone comes up with a better answer for you than *Well if you want to get there I wouldn't start from here ...*

Comment: Add $omp threadprivate for all saved variables

Comment: One way is to declare an array of `seed` that you index with the OpenMP `thread_id`. The length should be the maximal number of OpenMP threads. When called from the serial part of the code, you can use index 1 for instance.

Comment: @FrancoisJacq is that done when the parallel region is defined? I was under the impression that can't be done for local variables in functions.

Comment: you can do it for any saved variable anywhere